# Canonical MAAS offline installation

Tags: snap, maas, canonical

I need to install Canonical’s maas OFFLINE but I cannot find any information about how to do so.  I’d have preferred to use RPM packages but seem to be forced into using SNAP.  I have therefore installed and enabled SNAP.

How to get the maas SNAP downloaded though ??

Comment: MAAS is available via both Deb and Snap packages. You are welcome to package it for RPM if you wish -- it is Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

> online

```
#snap download core ; snap download core22 ; snap download maas
```

The downloads are not very big if anyone is wondering (I was)

```
# du -sh *
8.0K    core_16202.assert
106M    core_16202.snap
8.0K    core22_1033.assert
75M     core22_1033.snap
8.0K    maas_28521.assert
133M    maas_28521.snap
```

> offline
> Install core then core22 then maas

```
#snap ack core_16202.assert ; snap install ./core_16202.snap
#snap ack core22_1033.assert ; snap install ./core22_1033.snap
#snap ack maas_20521.assert ; snap install ./maas_20521.snap
```

[offline maas snap installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYLMB.png)